# LINQ query issue in DataContext

Tags: .net, linq, linq-to-sql, .net-4.0, linq-to-objects

```
 var activecommcontacts = 
   CorporateCalendarDataContext.ActiveCommunicationContacts.Where(p=>systemUserMinistries.Contains(p.MinistryId)).Select(p => p);                                  
    var distinctcomm = 
   CorporateCalendarDataContext.ActiveDistinctCommunicationContacts.Select(r => r);        

    IQueryable<ActiveDistinctCommunicationContact> options   
             = (from orig in distinctcomm   
                      let userid = orig.SystemUserId   
                      let name = orig.Name   
                      let nameandnumber = orig.NameAndNumber   
                      from b in activecommcontacts   
                      let actuserid = b.SystemUserId  
                      where userid == actuserid  
                      select new ActiveDistinctCommunicationContact  
                                 {  
                                     Name = name,  
                                     SystemUserId = userid,  
                                     NameAndNumber = nameandnumber  
                                 }).AsQueryable();
```

I am getting a SystemInvalidOperationException with the message
"The query contains references to    items defined on a different data context."

I even tried to work around it by doing it this way:

```
IQueryable<ActiveDistinctCommunicationContact> options = 
(from distinctcomm in CorporateCalendarDataContext.ActiveDistinctCommunicationContacts
 from activecommcontacts in activecommcontacts
 where activecommcontacts.SystemUserId == distinctcomm .SystemUserId
 select new 
    { 
        distinctcomm .SystemUserId, 
        distinctcomm .Name, 
        distinctcomm.NameAndNumber 
    }).AsQueryable();
```

I am getting a SystemInvalidOperationException with the message

"The query contains references to items defined on a different data context."

I wanted to point out that ActiveDistinctCommunicationContact and ActiveCommunicationContact are VIEWS in the same datacontext CorporateCalendarDataContext.
I even refreshed my DBML in the designer.
But I keep getting this annoying exception "The Query contains references to items on a different    data context".  I am not understanding why this is happening when the views belong to the same data context. I went to some of these issues on stackoverflow.com but I just cannot get this query to work. Can you help please.

```
public List<int> GetSystemUserMinistryList() {
    var dc = new CorporateCalendar.Data.CorporateCalendarDataContext(); //"param1", "param2", "param3");
    List<int> userMinistries = new List<int>();
    var systemUserMinistries = dc.GetTable<CorporateCalendar.Data.ActiveSystemUserMinistry>();
    foreach (CorporateCalendar.Data.ActiveSystemUserMinistry activeSystemUserMinistry in systemUserMinistries) { 
        if (activeSystemUserMinistry.SystemUserId == this.Id) {
            userMinistries.Add(activeSystemUserMinistry.MinistryId);
        }
    }

    return userMinistries;
}

private static CorporateCalendarDataContext CorporateCalendarDataContext {
    get { 
        var dc = new CorporateCalendarDataContext(); //"param1", "param2", "param3");
        return dc;
    }
}
```

Comment: First: format your question properly. Second: the exception means you are holding on to objects pulled from a different context instance, not necessarily different content type. Are you holding on to objects beyond the scope of the context?

Comment: I am not holding onto an object from a different context instance. I need to use two instances of the same data context as each refer to a different view in the DBML.

Comment: where is systemUserMinistries defined?  Is that using the other context?  I would understand this error if so.

Comment: private static CorporateCalendarDataContext CorporateCalendarDataContext {
        get {
            var dc = new CorporateCalendarDataContext(); //"param1", "param2", "param3");
            return dc;
        }
    }

Comment: I have added the other methods you were asking for more detail.Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I have understood your question and updates correctly...

I think it looks like you have the property:

```
private static CorporateCalendarDataContext CorporateCalendarDataContext {
    get {
        var dc = new CorporateCalendarDataContext(); //"param1", "param2", "param3");
        return dc;
    }
}
```

so every time you get that property you are getting a new context instance created so even though these two lines for example:

```
var activecommcontacts = CorporateCalendarDataContext.ActiveCommunicationContacts.Where(p=>systemUserMinistries.Contains(p.MinistryId)).Select(p => p);                                  
var distinctcomm = CorporateCalendarDataContext.ActiveDistinctCommunicationContacts.Select(r => r);
```

are using the same property, they will have a different context, hence the exception you are seeing.

You need to keep the context around for longer than you are doing so either do this:

```
var context = CorporateCalendarDataContext;
var activecommcontacts = context.ActiveCommunicationContacts.Where(p=>systemUserMinistries.Contains(p.MinistryId)).Select(p => p);                                  
var distinctcomm = context.ActiveDistinctCommunicationContacts.Select(r => r);  
// This context should be used for anything that you want to join together in the same query ...
```

or make that property store the context once it creates it, like this:

```
private static CorporateCalendarDataContext _context;
private static CorporateCalendarDataContext CorporateCalendarDataContext {
    get {
        if(_context == null)
            _context = new CorporateCalendarDataContext(); //"param1", "param2", "param3");
        return _context;
    }
}
```

Whatever you feel happier with and that fits your application design.

I am concerned that it is a static property, however, so that last approach may cause you additional issues if you keep the context for too long.

You need to be careful with data contexts and their lifetimes as they are tricky but there is a lot of information available on them.  Take a look at this blog article, for example:  [Entity Framework Context Lifetime Best Practices](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2010/02/07/entity-framework-context-lifetime-best-practices.aspx) and this post: [How to decide on a lifetime for your objectcontext](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/05/07/tip-18-how-to-decide-on-a-lifetime-for-your-objectcontext.aspx).

Comment: I like your answer. I did find the issue as I disabled the context called before the method to perform the code indicated above is called. It was'nt these 2 datacontext's as you mentioned. But the one you do'nt see in the caller. I did not even think it was an issue, when you opened my eyes of doubt in your pervious messages. Thank you your answer is the closest.

Comment: No problem - glad you found the problem!  The whole delayed execution thing of LINQ can make it hard to track down exactly what the root cause of things is sometimes.